# How to make siri speak items in a list?

Tags: siri, sirishortcuts

I have a list in a siri shortcut. I passed it to the "Choose an Item from List" and it works when I open the shortcut from the shortcuts app, I can see the list just fine, so there is no problem with the list itself.
However, when I launch the shortcut from siri, when she gets to the list part, she just says: "which one?" then prompts me to speak the item I want. She doesn't speak the items list though.
Is there a work around this?
I know she does speak the items if I went with the "Choose from Menu" action, but the thing is that the items I want her to speak aren't predefined list.

Answer (score 0):

You can add [this](https://www.icloud.com/shortcuts/0c8cc30cb4b4420ebfcb22016361ad4e) to your shortcut. If you don't want Siri to say "Here are the available options: " you can remove the text box and the speak action.